# static and dynamic host configuration approaches?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, dhcp

I'm currently revising for an exam and I'm stuck on a question which is:

> "Explain the static and dynamic host configuration approaches."

I'm unsure if the answer is correct but what I've write is this:

static host configuration are hard-coded addresses that will only work on one specific network segment, which is intended for stationary computers

dynamic host configurations work best with portable computers like laptops that move between network segments.

that's my answer, could anyone help me to understand if this is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the difference. But there s a lot more than what you have stated.

**DHC** :  Used to configure IP addresses automatically to the systems without any intervention of network administrator.

***For Eg***. When you register for a new internet connection, your ISP(network administrator, in this case) will provide you access to the DHCP server which ll allot you the IP address on the runtime.

1. To prevent the same IP address being assigned to two different computers
2. Also the main use is, ISP s will have a range of IP addresses with them. You ll be assigned any of their IPs dynamically by DHCP Server when your lease time expires for a particular IP that have been assigned earlier

---

**SHC** : Used to manually configure the IP addresses to systems.

1. When you knew how many systems are going to be present exactly inside the network
2. And when you want to uniquely identify a system in the ntwk using its IP address

***For Eg***. When you configure LAN in your house, between, say, around 4 computers. You will know exactly the number of systems in the group. So you don't have to allot a DHCP Server to allot the IP addresses for these 4 systems. YOu manually configure them

Hope that helps :)